# wrong syntax in very short package

Tags: packages, contexts, usage-messages

Here is a  very short package

```
BeginPackage["WZ`Au`"]
Unprotect @@ Names["WZ`Au`*"];
ClearAll @@ Names["WZ`Au`*"];
sfs::usage = "sfs[fun]: outputs WI[#]"
```

This yields error

```
Message::name: Message name MessageName[sfs,usage] is not of the form symbol::name or symbol::name::language.
```

and the package

```
Begin["`Private`"]
sfs[W_]=Module[{x,WI,Z},
WI=Integrate[W[x],{x,0,#}]&;
{WI}
]
End[]
Protect @@ Names["WZ`WZ`*"];
EndPackage[]
```

does not work in Mathematica 11.3, unless I comment the usage out

Comment: Try adding a `;` at the end of the `sfs::usage` line. It works for me on 12.0

Comment: Even after commenting the usage out, the remaining one line module does not work, even though the individual commands do: W = -(1/7) E^(-3 x/2) - E^(-x/2) + (15 E^(x/4))/7;
WI = Integrate[W, {x, 0, #}] &;
FullSimplify[WI[x]]